# Printing and handling files with specific character encoding

Tags: c, character-encoding, ascii, file-handling, windows-1252

I am training **file handling in C** and I have a problem when I `scanf();` a name, such as "Vinícius" which has an **accented letter**, and `fwrite();` it on a file the output is "Vin¡cius" and when i `fread();` this file and `printf();` on the console the output is also "Vin¡cius". But when I output it as integers the fourth number, that representes the fourth letter "í", is 161 and after searching for the ASCII table I was very confused to see that [161 is in fact the decimal value of "í"](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) but only on the **CP437 encoding** and my PC apparently uses the **Windows-1252 encoding** which defines that 161 is the decimal value of "¡". How would I print and use the functions `fread();` and `fwrite();` in the character encoding my PC understands ?

**P.S: I don't know if this has something to do with my IDE but I use CodeBlocks**

Comment: You may want to take a look at the function [`setlocale`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale). This may allow you to change the codepage. Your compiler probably has platform-dependant documentation on this function, so you should check your compiler's documentation, too.

Comment: According to the [documentation of the Microsoft version of the function `setlocale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=vs-2019), that function allows you to change the code page. However, this probably only applies if you are using the Microsoft compiler. if you are using gcc or clang, the behavior of the function is probably different.